# How to separate logging for an API

Tags: rest, logging, devops

What are the best practices for separating/storing logs for an API service/client?

- Should logs be separated by severity?
- Should logs be separated by purpose?
- Should I log requests to one file and log information to another?

The approach I was considering taking was to generate a UUID for each request that comes into my application and then from there tag application-specific logs with the UUID generated for the request.

I don't know if this is a common approach, but this gives me the ability to go back and look specifically for the request of interest while not cluttering my application logs with tons of requests.

Answer (score 1):

Like most things, it depends on how you're implementing your application and what you want to achieve.

Are you using Splunk or some other tool to monitor your logs? If so, there will likely be no need to use a UUID.

How large is the system you're architecting this logging for? If it's massive, it'll likely have production logs, perf/testing/dev logs, and then they'll be searchable by their endpoints or whatever identifiable, convenient method you decide on.

Are you asking how they should be separated for storage capacity reasons? Some logs (prod) need to stick around much longer than others (perf/testing/dev). So that's something to consider, because storage can become more expensive if you can't clear your logs.

Lots of other stuff to consider, but I hope that helps you get started, at least.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding where to log**
Usually, I would recommend to have everything logged into one file/place, so logs could be investigated uniformly. Ir request/response body's get too big it may be useful to make it possible to disable request/response body logging at all by the configuration change.

**Regarding WHAT to log**
If by an API you mean REST API or any other Web Service-related technology (something over HTTP), I would suggest to log at least:

- Request address
- Request headers
- Request body (if any)
- Response code
- Response headers
- Response body
- Any transaction indentificator, if a transaction involves more than one call to services

So the log record could look like:

```
Transaction GUID: xxx
Request: URL: https://localhost/, Method: GET, HEADERS: [Headers List], Body: "<RequestBody />"
Response: Status: 200, HEADERS: [Headers List], Body: "<ResponseBody />"
```